# Can I have multiple Svelte components on HTML page?

Tags: svelte

Is it possible to have a plain HTML page and have Svelte components injected at multiple places, like with [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)? So I don't want to use Svelte as a Singe Page Application (SPA), but use Svelte components on existing HTML pages. And is it possible to let the separate Svelte components to communicate with each other using the [event dispatcher](https://svelte.dev/docs#createEventDispatcher), and to share state using the [Context API](https://svelte.dev/docs#setContext) or [Svelte stores](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store)?

I am not in control of the rendered HTML, it comes from a CMS. So something like https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1849 will not work... I can't "compile" the HTML page with the Svelte compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes this is possible, in the script where you normally mount your Svelte App with `target: ...` you can mount several parts in different places:

```js
new Part1({
  target: mount1
});
new Part2({
  target: mount2
});
...
```

These components will all share the same store, but since they are all 'top level' components (as in: they have no common parent) you cannot use the ContextAPI, nor can you bubble events to a parent (which parent would that be anyway?)

You can however listen to events on the window level:

```
<svelte:window on:someeeventsomewhere={}></svelte:window>
```

If you then raise the *someventsomewhere* in one of your components it will be picked up by it's listeners.

The exact setup would of course depend on your exact use case.

Comment: Ok, that sounds promising! But when I don’t have control of the amount of “mount points”, is it possible to do the mounting at run-time, so select all DOM elements with a certain class and mount a specific component on all these DOM elements? And can I mount on a DOM element already containing ( server-side rendered) HTML and take over control?

Comment: You could use a querySelector and loop over the results to mount the Svelte component, for the existing DOM content, have a look at the 'hydratable' option in the docs.

Comment: Great insights! My last question to get the puzzle complete: is it possible to apply dynamic behavior to some existing markup, like is possible with Vue using **v-bind** and **v-on** as described in https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand

Comment: No, thats not possible. Svelte will not act an pre-existing markup unless you do it manually with queryselectors and innerhtml/-text.